# OOJS Multilevel Inheritance

Tags: javascript

In Javascript if, C-->B-->A (A is the parent which is inherited by B and C inherits B), Is it possible to restrict such that C doesn't inherit the properties of A.

PFB the code for the same,

```
function a(name) {
this.Name = name;
this.GetName = function () {
    alert(this.Name);
},
this.MethodOfA = function () {
    alert(this.Name + ' method of A --');
}
}

function b(name) {
a.call(this, name);
this.Name = name;
this.GetName = function () {
    alert(this.Name);
},
this.MethodOfB = function () {
    alert(this.Name + ' method of B --');
}
}

b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);

function c(name) {
b.call(this, name);
this.Name = name;
this.GetName = function () {
    alert(this.Name);
},
this.MethodOfC = function () {
    alert(this.Name + ' method of C --');
}
}

c.prototype.CallMe = function () {
    alert('call');
}

c.prototype = Object.create(b.prototype);

var aObj = new a('user1')
var bObj = new b('user2');
var cObj = new c('user3');

cObj.CallMe();
cObj.MethodOfC();
cObj.GetName();
cObj.MethodOfB();
cObj.MethodOfA();
```

In Javascript if, C-->B-->A (A is the parent which is inherited by B and C inherits B), Is it possible to restrict such that C doesn't inherit the properties of A.

Comment: Step away from OO and get back to your functionality.  You really don't need a complex OO model to accomplish most things.

Comment: `a.call(this, name); this.Name = name;`...??? But why?

Comment: `c.prototype = Object.create(b.prototype);` Don't use this if you don't want `C` to get properties of `A`

Comment: @Xlander, But i do need C to get the properties of B, but not A. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I need to make a call to the super class constructor from child class constructor in order to inherit the properties of the parent, hence I'm making a call to the constructor of object A from the constructor of object B(i.e a.call(this,name); )

Comment: @Manju you can do as mention in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note* I'm using the word "class" for the convenience, since these are rather only functions. In this case one thing you could do is restrict the `b` class so it will only inherit the methods of `a` if the current object being initialized is of class `b`:

```
function b(name) {
    if(this instanceof b) a.call(this, name);
    ...
}
```

When you call `b.call` from class `c` the `this instanceof b` will be false. This allows so only items that are of class `b` can get properties and methods from `a`.

**Edit**: You can also block just the class `c` as well by doing:

```
if( !(this instanceof c) ) a.call(this, name);
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/r2xLjz7o/) where I created a new class `d` (also doing `b.call()`) that does inherit from `a` where `c` does not.

Comment: typeof `this` will always be `"object"`, you're looking for `this instance of b`

Comment: @self Your completely right, thanks for the correction.